# Intercept type error

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to intercept type error and return own value ?
Consider scenario:
I have my own lib that in case of undefined or null returns some value

```
if (typeof value === 'undefined' || value === null) return Nothing;
```

so if you use this

```
mylib(null) // -> Nothing
mylib(1) // -> Just(1)
```

That is all good but if I pass in object with un-existing property like this

```
var a = {};
a.b = {};
mylib(a.b.c.d) // -> c is not an Object and does not have property d
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined
```

So what I would like is to intercept type errors and return Nothing instead and I want to do it in native js and I don't want to pass in properties to check in array or delimited string or something. So far I didn't find a way to do it.

I saw some examples of redefining window.onerror() but wondering if there is elegant way of preventing type errors dynamically.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If it would return the same error for everything it becomes impossible to debug.

Comment: No I would like to do it only for calls to mylib()

Comment: That error occurs before a call to `mylib()`. So how would you be able to intercept it? :)

Comment: Yes so I wanted to know for sure if there is no way of wrapping it somehow and return something else without using try{mylib(something)}catch(e){}

Comment: FWIW, this sample does *not* result in a `TypeError`, `(1).d` is just `undefined`.

Comment: I agree with @SunnyPatel, the type error occurs in the parent scope.
The javascript engine explore a.b.c.d before seeing your code.
You can't catch up the type error in the child scope.

Comment: @deceze Ok I edited the question - so no way to do this guys? I suspected so...

Comment: And no, this is not something your library should be worrying about, since that is completely changing how Javascript works. If you want to be able to catch errors in `mylib(a.b.c.d)`, then how about `var d = a.b.c.d; mylib(d);`. It's outside the responsibility of `mylib` to be worrying about.

Comment: I wanted to abstract it away so that you don't have to worry about checking of the var, if you get Nothing you would know you don't have what you looking for without nasty errors in console. Ok thank you all!

Comment: Or it is maybe something special in your library. And the user of your function can pass a direct value or an object. And you can test the object.d ... But I don't think it's really your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can use [ES6Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to achieve that.
This is especially useful if you want to apply your logic to only few objets.

NOTE that ES6 proxies are not supported by most of the browsers but you can try some shims.

Unfortunatelly you can't handle it globally since:

- window.onerror is called when an error is thrown. If an error is thrown you can't go back to the line of code where error was thrown and run it again.
- ES6 Proxy got some limitations. I highly recommend to read about it:  http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_proxies.html

The only option you can do for your library is to do something like this:

```
Option.getProperty(object, 'a.b.c.d') // returns Nothing or Just instance
```

Comment: Yes this seems like the thing I wanted to do. Just need to try and use it with shim until all browsers support it. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the post as "resolution"